# Multiple facebook like page count by core php

Tags: php

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pepsius/?fields=fan_count&access_token=<access_token>
```

I don't need facebook graph. I don't want to ask to client his/her facebook credential like app ID, client Key etc.

Comment: Nice! Rise up! We don't need no Facebook! Now, on a more serious note: what's the question exactly?

Comment: I think it's possible by core php but I don't know

Comment: Please give us a piece of code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can uese file_get_contents() function and get like, view etc.